# How can I convert Key Hash to bech32 in Cardano serialization lib?

Tags: cardano-serialization-lib

I generate my Key Hash Using the Following Function

```
const getAddressKeyHash = (address) => {
  return toHex(
    Cardano.Instance.BaseAddress.from_address(
      Cardano.Instance.Address.from_bech32(address)
    )
      .payment_cred()
      .to_keyhash()
      .to_bytes()
  );
};
```

Now i need to revert this back to Bech32. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Hashing is a one way function; the purpose of it is to verify the authenticity of data, *not* to encrypt data.

If you hash a piece of data, it should be impossible to revert the hash back to it's original form; this is a key operating principle of any hash function.

Generally, when a key-hash is used there should be a point in the process where an associated public/private key is supplied, and is used in combination with the key-hash to perform some sort of true/false evaluation.